# Using JQuery to manipulate HTML elements created from XSLT

Tags: jquery, xslt

Sorry if the title doesn't explain things well.

I have a situation where I am using DHTMLX AJAX component to display XSLT out to HTML.  So the idea is this:

1. There is a containing HTML page with a DIV which the xslt will be displayed into.
2. The xslt file of course which is very simple.. just display a couple of XML elements
   into `<p>` tags.
3. The XML dynamically generated.

Now all works well, it renders the output perfectly on most of the later browsers, and the rendering etc isn't the problem...

What I want to do now is to use JQuery to do something simple like show/hide a

tag etc.. which has a unique id of course.

The way I am doing it is to add the JQuery include into the HTML containing page, and have some Javascript/JQuery in the HEAD section of that HTML page - i.e. like you would normally if just a plain old HTML page.

JQuery doesn't seem to "see" the `<p id='test'>` tag which is rendered from the XSLT?  even though (to best of my knowledge) the XSLT is valid/formed well and displays perfectly ok?

Something silly I am obviously missing ... either conceptually or coding wise???

Thanks in advance, any help grateful!

Comment: does that id is predictable? also, the xml scheme has any type of pattern that you can use (e.g. a serie of divs could be assigned to a funcion in jquery using $('#container > div').live(function () { ... }) )

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery code may be running before your AJAX code finishes.  Try the live function:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

live() binds events to current and future elements that match a selector.

Answer (score 2):

If the XML is loaded via AJAX, then you'll need to apply the jQuery function on the element after it's loaded or using a live handler (depending on the event you are handling).  If you attempt to apply it on page load without using a live handler, then the element doesn't yet exist and thus the selector won't match it and any handlers won't be applied.